# How to assign awk output to netcat with delay after every element?

Tags: bash, awk, delay, netcat

I want to transfer first field of a csv file, but with a certain delay e.g. 1 second after every element.  I am using awk to pull the first field and then send it using netcat. I am using the following command but it has no delay.

```
awk -F, '{print  $1}' sample.csv | netcat -lk 9999
```

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do it in `bash` and use  `sleep 1`

Comment: @Jotne : we had the same idea :)

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://expect.sourceforge.net/ -- it automates some of the interactive tasks which you are trying to do using `sleep`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use system within awk to execute shell commands such as sleep.

```
awk -F, '{system("sleep 1");print  $1}' sample.csv | netcat -lk 9999
```

A word of warning though, using system can sometimes make it difficult to cancel a command half way through with `^C` as it cancels the system call but not awk.

Comment: I'd prefer using the shell over awk's system since with that Awk calls shell passing arguments to it, then shell summons `sleep`, having 1 extra process on every loop. Although it's not really necessary for such a trivial task.

Comment: @konsolebox: totally agree with you

Comment: @IdrissNeumann I have to delay 0.04 sec. I was able to that with this one, but not with shell. How can I delay 0.04 sec with your version?

Comment: @konsolebox i just thought i would provide a method for use in an awk program although in this example i agree that using pure shell is better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `bash` instead of `awk` in this case :

```
while IFS="," read -ra array; do echo "${array[0]}"; sleep 1; done < sample.csv|netcat -lk 9999
```

Comment: The solution is wrong: `netcat` is called for each line, rather than once and having the input throttled in one sec intervals

Comment: You missed `echo "$array"`.

Comment: @konsolebox : you could refresh ;)

Comment: @IdrissNeumann +1. And this is my version: `while IFS=, read -r A B; do echo "$A"; sleep 1; done < sample.csv | netcat -lk 9999`

Comment: @konsolebox yeah it's good idea to use a trash variable like that. Why don't post it in a new answer? :)